# How to set Spline chart 3d in .NET

Tags: c#, forms, charts, series, spline

I am using the chart component of .NET Framework 4.5 in C#.

When I fill that component with values that do not have the same gap to each other and set the ChartArea.Area3dStyle.Enable3d property to true, there is almost no impact on the chart until I equalize the gaps between the values in the series.

```
DataPoint dataPoint1 = new DataPoint(0D, 20D);
DataPoint dataPoint2 = new DataPoint(1D, 30D);
DataPoint dataPoint3 = new DataPoint(200D, 50D);
DataPoint dataPoint4 = new DataPoint(300D, 20D);
DataPoint dataPoint5 = new DataPoint(400D, 0D);
DataPoint dataPoint6 = new DataPoint(500D, 30D);
DataPoint dataPoint7 = new DataPoint(600D, 10D);
DataPoint dataPoint8 = new DataPoint(700D, 10D);

series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint2);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint3);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint4);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint5);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint6);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint7);
series1.Points.Add(dataPoint8);

chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set various parameters here. The one that directly makes up for the automtic downscaling with your large x-values is  `PointDepth`

```
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
chartArea1.Area3DStyle.PointDepth = 999; // pick a value you like
```

The best way to explore the many wonders of the `Chart` control is to play with it in the designer. When you have found a good setting you can go to the `yourForm.Designer.cs` file and look at the generated code; while you are not advised to fool around with it is a valuable resource for many obscure settings..

Unfortunately the maximum `PointDepth`  is 1000 and with x-values larger than 300-500 the 3D-effect is still rather weak. Maybe you can downscale your values?

Comment: I gathered more information about my problem: if I use different gaps between values e.g. the x-values are 0, 1, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 that problem occurs. --> edited post.

Comment: That's almost right; it seems as if the 3D depth is calculated from the smallest gap in the points sequence. Maybe the resoning is that for smaller gaps and thus sharper angles deeper curve areas would overlap too much..? No idea if there is a workaround short of changing/dropping some data.